# Will random text and links hidden by CSS around our content to prevent it from being crawled and parsed prevent Google from indexing those pages?

Tags: seo, html, css, google-index, dynamic

I have a Q/A website which is lunched for about 3 months. I don't know why the single pages will not be indexed in the google. For example when I search for `جهت مستفیض شدن از ماه محرم`, I will see the page-list of asked questions  instead of the single page of that specific question which is related to that entry in the google search result page.

Today I was thinking of this: Currently the whole html structure (dom) is generated dynamically for single pages *(single pages == pages that contain a question and its answers, like this page your looking at)*. Here is a simplified of the HTML structure of a question which doesn't have any answer:

```
<div class="wefgwe">
    <p>whatever</p>
    <span>question title</span>
    <a>link</a><div></div>
    <p>question body</p>
</div>
```

And when you refresh the same page, you probably see the HTML structure as the following:

```
<div class="jerfeg">
    <div>question title</div>
    <p>question body</p>
</div>
```

And refresh again:

```
<div class="fcsfwswsfr">
    <div><div></div>question title</div>
    <span>question body</span>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

See? everything is dynamic. Note that just the `question title` and `question body` will be appear in the user's browser. The rest will be hidden with the dynamic generated CSS.

My purpose of doing that is making the data safe against being crawled/parsed. Anyway, I want to know, is it harmful for SEO and getting indexed in the Google?

Comment: Read more: 
* https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-sites-using-a-lot-of-javascript-may-not-be-moved-to-mobile-first-indexing/268571/
* http://www.thesempost.com/google-indexes-ranks-javascript-pages-two-waves-days-apart/
* https://moz.com/blog/javascript-and-seo
* https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353

Comment: "My purpose of doing that is making the data safe against being crawled/parsed" -- well there is your answer.  If you have obfuscated it such that it can't be crawled and parsed, then Googlebot isn't going to be able to crawl and parse it and Google isn't going to index it.

Comment: Hiding data from crawlers also hides data from search engine crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

In summary: You created a website that requires human interaction and hides from Googlebot, where questions are answered dynamically, but you want Google to give you a good (SEO) rank?

The best solution I can offer (without actually seeing the website you are referring to) is to suggest that you create "landing pages" for your website. 
Each of your primary topics should have their own unique "Landing Page" specifically coded to maximize SEO effectiveness. Those are the pages that Goodle will rank. Then add a robots.txt file indicating which landing pages you want Google to rank and which areas are "off limits".

This approach will give you the best of both worlds. Your focused topics will be ranked on Google, while protecting the content of your questions and answers.
[Understanding Landing Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_page)
[Learn more about Google SEO Revisions](https://searchengineland.com/google-revamps-seo-starter-guide-288232)
[What to put in your robots.txt file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Answer (score 0):

Google doesnt encourage excessive use of Ajax based content that appears on request since Google, in most cases, is unable to read that content and it could create problem in Google Indexing.
It's better to use other ways like IP Blocking on excessive requests for content scraping issue and let your main content appear on the page so that Google can read it properly.